# AS3: Scoping issue with -warn-scoping-change-in-this

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I wanted to enable all compiler warnings in Flex to resolve them in my code. But there is one warning which I can't figure out how to solve it. Here is some example code:

```
package lib
{
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;

    public class player
    {
        private function tmp(event:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
        }

        public function player():void
        {
            super();
            var connection:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
            connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

On compiling with -warn-scoping-change-in-this I'm getting the following warning:

```
/var/www/test/src/lib/player.as(16): col: 59 Warning: Migration issue: Method tmp will behave differently in ActionScript 3.0 due to the change in scoping for the this keyword. See the entry for warning 1083 for additional information.

            connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, tmp);
```

Putting tmp as function inside player() will work but this is not what I want. I have even tried to use this.tmp as callback but there is no difference. Does somebody know how to solve this compiler warning?

Comment: Don't worry about that warning, it's only applicable when migrating code from AS2 to AS3, and obviously seing your code that is not your case.

Comment: I like it to compile in the most strict modes. So it is my goal to solve this warning even if it is not really needed.

Comment: do you have anything inside your tmp function? if yes, then provide us with the contents.

Comment: This is the "original" code. This means that I have reduced my application to this testcase. But exactly this code is triggering the warning.

Comment: Is warning shown for any as3 program, or does it disappear if you remove `connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, tmp);` line? It seems that it will be always shown if you pass a function somewhere, because this function will behave differently in as2 and as3. It's sad to ruin your idealistic beliefs in compiler warnings, but they are written by people and for people.

Answer (score 1):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/compilerWarnings.html

**This is a code migration warning. This warning is generated when a method of an object is used as a value, usually as a callback function. In ActionScript 2.0, functions are executed in the context they are called from. In ActionScript 3.0, functions are always executed in the context where they were defined. Thus, variable and method names are resolved to the class that the callback is part of, rather than relative to the context it is called from, as in the following example:**

```
class a 
{ 
   var x; 
   function a() { x = 1; } 
   function b() { trace(x); } 
}

var A:a = new a();
var f:Function = a.b; // warning triggered here
var x = 22;
f(); // prints 1 in ActionScript 3.0, 22 in ActionScript 2.0
```

Comment: I have already read the documentation but it hasn't helped me to solve this issue.

Comment: You should not worry about it at all. As @danii mentioned in his comment, this is just 'for your attention', if you were using AS2 before, some behavior can become a surprise for you. Never the less, the code is absolutely correct.

Comment: The code may be correct but I'm wondering why Flex is complaining about the callback. I would prefer to let all warnings be enabled in case I could make a "mistake" in the future. So I'm trying to find a way to solve this warning.

Comment: @Sworddragon you'll see all meaning warnings by default. It's nice, that you're worried about clear code. But these migration warnings mean only "Hey look, it's ActionScript 3 now, it could behave unexpectedly for you if you used to write in ActionScript 2 before". It's just to pay your attention and nothing more.

Comment: This would mean that this warning is absolutely useless in this code. In this case I would consider that this could be a bug in the Flex compiler. I will continue to try to find a solution and if I will fail I will open a bugreport on the Adobe bugtracker.

Comment: I can't understand, what's not clear for you in my explanation. This is not a bug. The warning is useless for you. But it's not useless for developers, who migrate from AS2 to AS3. Are you one of them? If not, just turn off the option

Comment: I'm not migrating from AS2 to AS3 but there must be a way to resolve every warning without disabling it. At least I have never seen such behavior before in other languages. So there are only 2 possibilities:

1. It is solveable without disabling the warning.
2. It is a bug in the Flex compiler.

Comment: I have now found a potential solution for this problem. Instead of using "tmp" as callback "function(event:NetStatusEvent):void { tmp(event); }" will work.

Comment: @Sworddragon using anonymous functions can cause memory leaks. What was the reason asking on stackoverflow, while you have your own strong opinion.

Comment: `using anonymous functions can cause memory leaks.`

A flash application can't have memory leaks (just objects could be remaining). Only the flash player can leak but this would be a bug.

`What was the reason asking on stackoverflow, while you have your own strong opinion`

I wanted a solution to fix this warning and not just to disable it.

Comment: "A flash application can't have memory leaks (just objects could be remaining)" and that's a memory leak... You can't "fix" this warning since it's not telling you that you need to change something. The flag you are activating is not relevant for your project - fix the warning by turning it off.

Comment: Since the function is not stored in a variable there should nothing "leak". The garbage collection should handle this. But this is more or less offtopic. Maybe somebody know a better solution as mine. Otherwise this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

That warning is only placed there to let you know that the behavior of your code might have changed in case you are migrating your code from AS2 to AS3 (which the compiler has no way of knowing beforehand). You should **only** enable the compiler option `-warn-scoping-change-in-this` **when you are migrating your code from AS2 to AS3**.

So, as I said in the comments, you shouldn't worry about that warning, since obviously seing your code that is not your case and you don't need that compiler option enabled.

Comment: But there must be a reason why this warning is triggering on this code.

Comment: @Sworddragon the reason is mentioned in documentation. You'd better switch off this option.